# Using Javascript animate() Method to control 2 separate DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate

I am trying to use a on click Animate DIV using this JavaScript code:

```
$("#meetLegal").click((function() {
        var i = 0;
        return function() {
            $("#legalTeam").animate({
            height: (++i % 2) ? 300 : 0
            }, 500);
        }})());

$("#explorePractice").click((function() {
    var i = 0;
        var i = 0;
        return function() {
            $("#practiceAreas").animate({
            height: (++i % 2) ? 300 : 0
            }, 500);
        }})());
```

I am using two buttons "meetLegal" and "explorePractice" to slide down 2 DIVs. It works in a way that when I click each button, its particular DIV open and closes, but I want to work it in a way that if 1 DIV is on the SLIDE DOWN state, and you click on the 2nd button, it should close the first DIV and SLIDE DOWN the 2nd DIV. Thank you.

Comment: Jeezes, jQuery has slideDown and slideUp, did you try using those instead of this madness ?

Answer (score 0):

At a low level, you can try something like this,

```
$("#meetLegal").click(function () {
    $("#practiceAreas").slideUp(500, function () {

        $("#legalTeam").slideDown(500, function () {

        });
    });
});

$("#explorePractice").click(function () {
    $("#legalTeam").slideUp(500, function () {
        $("#practiceAreas").slideDown(500, function () {

        });
    });

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3UM8c/)**